# difference and advantages between BOOL and bool

Tags: c++, boolean

I've been playing with some functions that return BOOL. I know how to use them but whats the difference between BOOL and bool? I've also looked at some example code from directX and they use it as a int? Is there a advantage to using int, bool, or BOOL? My main question is Which should I be using?

Comment: [`BOOL` is a type alias for `int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx). Use it if the function takes or returns `BOOL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Is there a advantage to using int, bool, or BOOL?`

One advantage of using `bool` over `BOOL` is that you can overload functions on `bool`.

```
// header file
void f( int  ); // ok
void f( BOOL); // ok, redeclares the same function
```

...

```
// source file
void f( int  ) { /*...*/ }   // ok
void f( BOOL) { /*...*/ }   // error, redefinition
```

For more information about why it makes sense to use `bool` over `BOOL` read this [gotw](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/026.htm) by Herb Sutter

Answer (score 5):

`BOOL` is a Windows-specific type name; it's a `typedef` (an alias) for `int`.

Historically, it was probably invented by Microsoft before the built-in `bool` type was added to C++.

For any new code that doesn't have to talk to the Windows API, just use `bool`.

Use `BOOL` only for code that has to conform to the Windows API.

(If the Windows API were being written from scratch today, presumably it would use C++'s built-in `bool` type rather than inventing its own. `BOOL` is a relic of history.)

Comment: I'm fairly sure I've seen at least one case of a function that returns `BOOL` having three possible return states, unfortunately. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: @chris: That would not surprise me. It would disgust me, but it would not surprise me.

Answer (score 1):

For the best type safety, in new code you should use bool for a boolean. If you interface with things like a BOOL, automatic type conversion will generally work for you, but otherwise you just treat BOOL as a legacy integer represented boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Most compilers will make the size of a `bool` 1 byte, whereas the size of an `int` is usually 4 bytes.
There is an obvious saving in space if you use `bool` for tightly packed structures in this case.

Now, in theory, moving and `int` around is faster than moving a byte (`int` is usually the native machine word). So in the sense of microoptimizations for maximum speed, a `BOOL` that equals an `int` is better than a `bool` that equal a byte.